# On change of dropdown options, ALL dropdowns are changing

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that is taking the value of the first dropdown option and showing the corresponding second dropdown (so `prod-select` links to `prod-var`).

This initially worked fine but I've now had to add a second lot of dropdowns (see the second prod-group div).

The problem I have is when I change the options in the first `prod-group` div, they also change the second `prod-group`, how can I get around that?

```
$('select[class*="var-"]').hide();
$('.prod-select').on('change', function() {
  $('select[class*="var-"]').hide(); //hide all select
  $(".var-" + this.value).show(); //show 
});
$('.prod-select').trigger('change') //trigger on page load
```

Then the HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prod-group">
  <select class="prod-select" name="product_cat">
    <option value="1">
      A
    </option>
    <option value="2">
      B
    </option>
  </select>

  <select class="var-1" name="product_var">
    <option value="">
      var 1
    </option>
  </select>
  <select class="var-2" name="product_var">
    <option value="">
      var 2
    </option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="prod-group">
  <select class="prod-select" name="product_cat">
    <option value="1">
      A
    </option>
    <option value="2">
      B
    </option>
  </select>

  <select class="var-1" name="product_var">
    <option value="">
      var 1
    </option>
  </select>
  <select class="var-2" name="product_var">
    <option value="">
      var 2
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dx29Lfo8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are targetting all select-box instead you can use `$(this).siblings("selectbox..")` to target only select which is required.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('select[class*="var-"]').hide();
$('.prod-select').on('change', function() {
  $(this).siblings('select[class*="var-"]').hide();
  $(this).siblings(".var-" + this.value).show();
});
$('.prod-select').trigger('change')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prod-group">
  <select class="prod-select" name="product_cat">
    <option value="1">
      A
    </option>
    <option value="2">
      B
    </option>
  </select>

  <select class="var-1" name="product_var">
    <option value="">
      var 1
    </option>
  </select>
  <select class="var-2" name="product_var">
    <option value="">
      var 2
    </option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="prod-group">
  <select class="prod-select" name="product_cat">
    <option value="1">
      A
    </option>
    <option value="2">
      B
    </option>
  </select>

  <select class="var-1" name="product_var">
    <option value="">
      var 1
    </option>
  </select>
  <select class="var-2" name="product_var">
    <option value="">
      var 2
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a combination of `closest` and `find`, `siblings` would be quicker but could fail if the elements you want to hide ever become nested, with this approach it will move to the parent div then search all decendants for the elements to hide:

```
$('.prod-select').on('change', function() {
     const $parentDiv = $(this).closest('.prod-group'); //Get the parent div
     $parentDiv.find('select[class*="var-"]').hide(); //hide
     $parentDiv.find(".var-" + this.value).show(); //show 
});
```